# Please Explain The Usage Of FirebaseRecyclerOption

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

i am using a **FirebaseecyclerOption**, but i don't know the use of it and also tell me how it perform it to populate and store data in model class, like it execute each time or its store all the data in the option and populate it into the model class please explain thanks, *and another question is how we can get only limited items from the database.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` class controls how FirebaseUI populates the `RecyclerView` with data from the Realtime Database. At a minimum you pass it a query or location to get the data from, and a Java class that will be instantiated to hold the data from each row in the view. For more on this, see the documentation on [using the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-the-firebaserecycleradapter).

To limit the data shown you have two options. You can either point to a location with less data, or use a query to limit what data is retrieved. The FirebaseUI documentation on [querying](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#querying) shows an example of that, and you find even more examples in the regular Firebase documentation on [sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: Yes, but how many times the FirebaseRecyclerOptions will excute i mean it will execute one time to get the snapshot of the data or it will increament upto the end of the data like in SQL select * from ?

Comment: i am confused just because the modal class dont contain an arraylist to store all the data retriving from the query so how its maintain the populates process

Comment: The `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` actively listens for changes to the database, and then updates the UI to reflect those changes. Give it a try by wiring it up in your app, and then making a change to your database in the Firebase console. It's quite magical if you've never seen it before. :)

Comment: And on your last comment: the data is actually maintained in a [`FirebaseArray` object](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseArray.java). The adapter instantiates a model object for every child node of the query/reference that you use.

Comment: thankyou so much now a bit clear after your last comment